# change the class definition with TS decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator

I'm trying to reproduce the **@Getters** of the common Java library Lombok. The result would be :

```js
@Getters()
export class Example {
  private property: string;
}
```

```js
const test = new Example();
console.log(test.getProperty());
```

To do this, I try to change the js class definition by override it with a TS Decorator:

```js
import { capitalize } from "lodash";

export const Getters = () => <T extends {new(...args:any[]):{}}>(constructor:T) => {  
  return class extends constructor {
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args);
      const props = Reflect.ownKeys(this);
      props.forEach((prop: string) => {
        const capitalizedKey = capitalize(prop);
        const methodName = `get${capitalizedKey}`;
        Reflect.defineProperty(this, methodName, { value: () => this[prop], configurable: false, enumerable: false });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

For the moment, I have this error **The X property does not exist on the X type.**

But I can have the result with this:

```js
console.log(test['getProperty']())
```

Doe's someone know how to change the class definition with TS decorator pls?

Playground: https://typescript-lodash-playground-1fuxpz.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the documentation. Decorators **do not** change the type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is not Java, you don't use getter methods and don't need to add `@Getters`. The idiomatic way to achieve this is to simply create a public property that can't be written to:

```
export class Example {
  readonly property: string;
  constructor(p: string) {
    this.property = p;
  }
}
```

or short

```
export class Example {
  constructor(readonly property: string) {}
}
```

then use

```
const test = new Example("demo");
console.log(test.property);
```